# TS2339: Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'MyComponent in vue-class-component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-class-components

Does anyone know how to properly tell to TypeScript how to get know about `Prop`'s `type` I entitled on the first picture?

1. This one guy declared `Prop` called `engine`. [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIlEB.png)

```
<script lang="ts">
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import { Component, Prop, Watch, Mixins } from 'vue-property-decorator';
 import pDebounce from 'p-debounce';

 // Define the props by using Vue's canonical way.
 export const FetcherProps = Vue.extend({
   props: {
     engine: Function
   }
 })
 // Use defined props by extending GreetingProps
 @Component
 class Fetcher extends FetcherProps {
   response: Array<any> | Promise<any> = [];
   fetch2: Function;

   // @Prop() engine!: Function;
   // @Prop({ default: null }) debounce!: null | number;
   // @Prop({ default: () => {} }) request!: Dictionary<any>;
   // @Prop({ default: true }) promisify!: boolean;

   get requestObject() {
     return { params: this.request };
   }
```

2. Here I am extending the component from the first one picture
   [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMDsc.png)

```
@Component({})
  class EmSearchEngine extends Fetcher {
```

3. (The same component from above picture) The problem is TypeScript can not infer engine type correctly [image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2xHh.png)

```
    render(h: CreateElement) {
      return h(Fetcher, {
        props: {
          debounce: 300,
          promisify: false,
          engine: this.engine <-- "TS2339: Property 'engine' does not exist on type 'EmSearchEngine'.,
          request: {
            ...this.initialQuery,
            ...this.query,
            cancelToken: new CancelToken((cancel) => {
              abortSearch = cancel;
            })
          }
```

Before that, I tried to use an example from example's folder in repo: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blob/master/example/src/App.vue but it didn't help me.

Is there something wrong with my code or I explicitly have to declare `engine` class' property on `EmSearchEngine` component?

Big thanks in advance for your help. Original github's issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/391

Comment: Please take a read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6294072 and also [ask] Please post the relevant code as code blocks in your question.

Comment: Fair enough. About to replace with source code. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried importing Vue from ‘vue-property-decorator’ rather than your current import?